# send array to stored producer codeigniter. #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

i m working on project in codeigniter.
i wanna call a stored producer from my model and send a array to it.
when i call method i got a error message.

my goal from this calling is get list of products in special category list.

here is my call sp

```
CALL Get_Products_List('',('1000','9UKXYZj4M2F5yN'),'','','','','','','','','','','','10',0,'code','Asc')
```

and here is my got error:

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Get_Products_List`(
IN `id` VARCHAR(14), IN `p_c_id` longtext, IN `code` VARCHAR(20)
, IN `model` VARCHAR(100), IN `name` VARCHAR(100), IN `price` VARCHAR(10)
, IN `price_unit` VARCHAR(14), IN `in_stock` VARCHAR(14), IN `is_special` VARCHAR(14)
, IN `is_new` VARCHAR(14), IN `has_warranty` VARCHAR(14), IN `b_id` VARCHAR(14)
, IN `product_type` VARCHAR(14), IN `psize` INT
, IN `ofset` INT, IN `order_by` VARCHAR(100), IN `order_by_sort` VARCHAR(10))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
SET @order_by_sort = UPPER(order_by_sort);

SELECT p.id,Get_Post_Score_Sum('1603',p.id) as average_score,ifnull(pc.name,'ندارد') as category_name,p.code,p.model,p.name,p.price,p.image,p.image_thumb
,ifnull(t1.name,'ندارد') as price_unit,p.discount,ifnull(t2.name,'ندارد') as in_stock
,ifnull(t3.name,'ندارد') as is_special,ifnull(t4.name,'ندارد') as is_new
,ifnull(t5.name,'ندارد') as has_warranty,ifnull(t6.name,'ندارد') as product_type
,ifnull(b.name,'ندارد') as brand_name
,p.registered_date 
FROM tbl_product as p 
inner join tbl_product_category as  pc on p.p_c_id=pc.id
inner join tbl_baseinfo as  t1 on p.price_unit=t1.id
inner join tbl_baseinfo as  t2 on p.in_stock=t2.id
inner join tbl_baseinfo as  t3 on p.is_special=t3.id
inner join tbl_baseinfo as  t4 on p.is_new=t4.id
inner join tbl_baseinfo as  t5 on p.has_warranty=t5.id
inner join tbl_baseinfo as  t6 on p.product_type=t6.id
inner join tbl_brand as  b on p.b_id=b.id
where  p.p_c_id in (p_c_id)
and p.code LIKE CONCAT('%', code , '%')
and p.model like CONCAT('%', model , '%') and  p.name LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%')
and p.price like CONCAT('%', price , '%') and  p.price_unit LIKE CONCAT('%', price_unit , '%')
and p.in_stock like CONCAT('%', in_stock , '%') and  p.is_special LIKE CONCAT('%', is_special , '%')
and p.b_id like CONCAT('%', b_id , '%') and  p.product_type LIKE CONCAT('%', product_type , '%')
order by
CASE WHEN order_by = 'category_name' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.p_c_id END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'code' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.code END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'model' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.model END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'name' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.name END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'price' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.price END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'price_unit' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.price_unit END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'discount' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.discount END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'in_stock' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.in_stock END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'is_special' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.is_special END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'is_new' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.is_new END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'has_warranty' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.has_warranty END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'product_type' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.product_type END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'brand_name' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.b_id END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'registered_date' AND @order_by_sort = 'ASC' THEN p.registered_date END ASC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'category_name' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.p_c_id END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'code' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.code END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'model' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.model END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'name' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.name END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'price' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.price END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'price_unit' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.price_unit END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'discount' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.discount END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'in_stock' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.in_stock END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'is_special' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.is_special END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'is_new' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.is_new END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'has_warranty' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.has_warranty END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'product_type' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.product_type END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'brand_name' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.b_id END DESC,
CASE WHEN order_by = 'registered_date' AND @order_by_sort = 'DESC' THEN p.registered_date END DESC


LIMIT psize OFFSET ofset; 

END
```

Comment: I think is better to not use store producers in mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not a PHP or Codeigniter error.
You should check your SQL query.